# Check if method returns right string

Tags: python

I got a class that is a linkedlist, and a method that returns a string of the elements, i.e

```
LL = linkedList() 
LL.addFirst(1.0)
LL.addLast('Two')
LL.addLast(3)

LL.string() = [1.0],['Two'],[3]
```

I want to unit test this piece, with

```
exp = '[1.0],['Two'],[3]'
assert LL.string() == exp
```

However, Python doesn't seems to to appreciate the string within a string, resulting

```
    exp = '[1.0],['Two'],[3]'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: may be use " ???

Answer (score 1):

In python you can mix single and double quotation marks like so:

```
exp = "[1.0],['Two'],[3]"
```

Comment: That was surely an easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the single-quotes by double-quotes, and it will work fine

```py
exp = "[1.0],['Two'],[3]"
assert LL.string() == exp
```

Comment: That was surely an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: Or escape the string delimiter like `print('It\'s working')` or use triple quotes `print('''"It's working" he said'''`.